# Silex and Doctrine mysql: how to return results from select all

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

The Doctrine provider provides a db service. Here is a usage example:

```
$app->get('/enc/{id}', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestas WHERE id_enc = ?";
    $post = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array((int) $id));

    return  "<h1>Encuestas</h1>".
                "<p>{$post['fec_enc']}</p>".
                "<p>{$post['opc1']}</p>".
                "<p>{$post['img1']}</p>".
                "<p>{$post['vot1']}</p>".
                "<p>{$post['opc2']}</p>".   
            "<p>{$post['img2']}</p>".
            "<p>{$post['vot2']}</p>".
            "<p>{$post['estado']}</p>";
});
```

this is array, the problem:

```
$app->get('/enc', function() use ($app) {


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestas";
    $post = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);


   return   ...;

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And what is a problem?

In the second piece of code db returns the array of associated arrays. and to show each item from it you have to use some kind of loop. The return example you provided is ugly, actually. Why don't you use some template engine (like twig for example)? Anyway you have to do something like:

```
$posts = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql); // posts - NOT post
foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo $post['fec_enc']; // or "echo '<p>' . $post['fec_enc'] . '</p>'", 
                           // but it's really ugly
    ... // rest of properties
}
```

Or using twig:

Render twig template:

```
return $app['twig']->render('<template_name>', array('posts' => $posts));
```

In twig template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.fec_enc }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Here is more about Silex templates: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html

Comment: you're right, there is no problem. I just thought a more fancy way to not use "echo" and twig. But like you said it's ugly...
I will use twig template now.